# Pass parameter to JsonSerialize

Tags: java, jackson

I have a rest service which send JSON. Before sending, I want to change one field, for example add `n` to price. `n` is a parameter, which comes from the client. How I can pass `n` to `JsonSerializer` without AOP and Reflection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with `SimpleModule`. 
Create `SimpleModule` and create your Serializer object manually and pass parameter to constructor. 
Here is example

Let say we have User model class like:

```
 package com;

public class User {

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public int getNumber() {
    return number;
}
public void setNumber(int number) {
    this.number = number;
}
private String name;
private int number;
```

}

Here is custom Serializer class like :

```
package com;


public class UserSerializer extends JsonSerializer<User>{
    private String n;

public UserSerializer(String n){
    this.n = n;
}
@Override
public void serialize(User user, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    if(user != null){
        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("name", "Hello, "+user.getName()+" : value of n : "+n);
        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

}

Here is your main class :

```
public class Application {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    User user = new User();
    user.setName("nitin");
    String n = "1111";  //this value comes from API
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addSerializer(User.class, new UserSerializer(n));

    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    xmlMapper.registerModule(module);

    String xml = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(user);
    System.out.println(xml);
}
```

}

and your out put should be like :

```
<User1 xmlns=""><name>Hello, nitin : value of n : 1111</name></User1>
```

If you want output in json, then use `ObjectMapper`.